# Reshape each array in a list of arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an list of arrays, I want to reshape each array in the list and then stack.

A sample below

```
C = np.array([[-127, -108, -290],
       [-123,  -83, -333],
       [-126,  -69, -354],
       [-146, -211, -241],
       [-151, -209, -253],
       [-157, -200, -254]])



D = np.array([[-129, -146, -231],
       [-127, -148, -238],
       [-132, -157, -231],
       [ -93, -355, -112],
       [ -95, -325, -137],
       [ -99, -282, -163]])



E = np.array(([[-141, -133, -200],
       [-132, -123, -202],
       [-119, -117, -204],
       [-107, -210, -228],
       [-101, -194, -243],
       [-105, -175, -244]]))


ArrayList = (C,D,E)
```

to reshape an individual array I do the following

```
newArray = ArrayList[0].reshape(1,-1)
```

and produces the desired result

```
array([[-127, -108, -290, -123,  -83, -333, -126,  -69, -354, -146, -211,
        -241, -151, -209, -253, -157, -200, -254]])
```

I tried writing a for loop to go through each item

```
newArray = []
for i in ArrayList:
    i.reshape(1,-1)
    newArray.append(i)
```

But I got the same product as what I started with.
The desired output is shown below

```
(array([[-127, -108, -290, -123,  -83, -333, -126,  -69, -354, -146, -211,
         -241, -151, -209, -253, -157, -200, -254]]),
 array([[-129, -146, -231, -127, -148, -238, -132, -157, -231,  -93, -355,
         -112,  -95, -325, -137,  -99, -282, -163]]),
 array([[-141, -133, -200, -132, -123, -202, -119, -117, -204, -107, -210,
         -228, -101, -194, -243, -105, -175, -244]]))
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your desired result multidimensional or flattened? The double [ are a red flag. You also might check out numpy hstack and vstack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to do this:

```py
newArray = []
for i in ArrayList:
    j = i.reshape(1,-1)
    newArray.append(j)

print(newArray)
```

Output:

```
[array([[-127, -108, -290, -123,  -83, -333, -126,  -69, -354, -146, -211,
        -241, -151, -209, -253, -157, -200, -254]]), 
array([[-129, -146, -231, -127, -148, -238, -132, -157, -231,  -93, -355,
        -112,  -95, -325, -137,  -99, -282, -163]]), 
array([[-141, -133, -200, -132, -123, -202, -119, -117, -204, -107, -210,
        -228, -101, -194, -243, -105, -175, -244]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a list comprehension?

```
newArray = [i.reshape(1,-1) for i in ArrayList]
```

Output:

```
[array([[-127, -108, -290, -123,  -83, -333, -126,  -69, -354, -146, -211,
         -241, -151, -209, -253, -157, -200, -254]]),
 array([[-129, -146, -231, -127, -148, -238, -132, -157, -231,  -93, -355,
         -112,  -95, -325, -137,  -99, -282, -163]]),
 array([[-141, -133, -200, -132, -123, -202, -119, -117, -204, -107, -210,
         -228, -101, -194, -243, -105, -175, -244]])]
```

Comment: thats a nice one liner

Answer (score 0):

`reshape()` does not guarantee that it will return a "view", as it is called in the docs, to the same array. See the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) for this. It could be a copy of the original array, hence you need to use the return value and append the return value to your array. This should fix your problem.

```py
import numpy as np

C = np.array([[-127, -108, -290],
       [-123,  -83, -333],
       [-126,  -69, -354],
       [-146, -211, -241],
       [-151, -209, -253],
       [-157, -200, -254]])



D = np.array([[-129, -146, -231],
       [-127, -148, -238],
       [-132, -157, -231],
       [ -93, -355, -112],
       [ -95, -325, -137],
       [ -99, -282, -163]])



E = np.array(([[-141, -133, -200],
       [-132, -123, -202],
       [-119, -117, -204],
       [-107, -210, -228],
       [-101, -194, -243],
       [-105, -175, -244]]))


ArrayList = (C,D,E)

newArray = []
for i in ArrayList:
    newArray.append(i.reshape(1,-1))

print(newArray)
```

Expected output

```
[array([[-127, -108, -290, -123,  -83, -333, -126,  -69, -354, -146, -211,
        -241, -151, -209, -253, -157, -200, -254]]), array([[-129, -146, -231, -127, -148, -238, -132, -157, -231,  -93, -355,
        -112,  -95, -325, -137,  -99, -282, -163]]), array([[-141, -133, -200, -132, -123, -202, -119, -117, -204, -107, -210,
        -228, -101, -194, -243, -105, -175, -244]])]
```

Comment: `i.reshape(1,-1)` doesn't work in-place,  copy or view.